# How to create a time lapse using google charts maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

Hi I am new to google charts maps api. I want to show map markers for each day of the week, each marker represents a location of purchase on that day. I then want to have a slider for the days, as we move the slider, the number of markers increases as the total sale from day 1 - day X keeps increases and end of the week it shows all the purchases.
I was able to use this link and https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map#Strings and show all the markers for the entire week, but unable to create a slider which does incremental marker placement based on the no. of purchases on that day and increase forward:
Here is my code, please let me know how should I proceed further

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
  google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['map'] }, {'mapType':['terrain']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

 function drawMap() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

    ['Address','Date'],
['160w kingsbridge rd 3A Bronx  NY 10463',9/1/14],
['3147 Broadway, NY 10026  NY 10463',9/2/14],
['22W 19th Street NY', 9/3/2013],

  ]);

var options = { showTip: true };

var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

map.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div" style="width: 1400px; height: 800px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No offense, but this site isn't here for people to do the legwork for you. We are here to identify and correct bugs and issues with code. You have not even made a decent attempt to accomplish what you're asking.

Comment: I totally understand that Russel, I tried using Fusion table but it is over shooting the limit (referred to this tutorial) http://piotrgisworks.blogspot.com/2014/01/google-fusion-table-and-data_10.html I would appreciate a direction in which I should be thinking to implement this feature.Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code for the slider? https://github.com/piotrkrosniak